# Technotrend CT2 4650 not working in fresh install

Tags: 16.04, usb, dvb, dvb-t

I have a Technotrend CT2 4650. It worked perfectly on a Ubuntu 16.04.02, which was a upgrade from the previous LTS line as far as I remember. The USB module was dvb_usb_dvbsky.

Then my SSD crashed, and I reinstalled 16.04.02 the other day. It's not discovered anymore. It's shown in lsusb of course, but the module does not seem to initialize it:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b48:3015 TechnoTrend AG
```

When I modprobe dvb_usb_dvbsky, this appears in dmesg:

```
[  175.468458] usbcore: registered new interface driver dvb_usb_dvbsky
```

I have tested the module on a PC running OpenSuSE, and the following turned up in dmesg:

```
[220841.422482] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[220841.563158] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0b48, idProduct=3015
[220841.563161] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[220841.563162] usb 1-2: Product: TechnoTrend USB2.0
[220841.563163] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: CityCom GmbH
[220841.563164] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 20151107
[220843.006483] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: found a 'TechnoTrend TT-connect CT2-4650 CI v1.1' in warm state
[220843.006543] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: will pass the complete MPEG2 transport stream to the software demuxer
[220843.006557] DVB: registering new adapter (TechnoTrend TT-connect CT2-4650 CI v1.1)
[220843.007850] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: MAC address: bc:ea:2b:65:04:ab
[220843.020459] i2c i2c-8: Added multiplexed i2c bus 9
[220843.020462] si2168 8-0064: Silicon Labs Si2168-B40 successfully identified
[220843.020463] si2168 8-0064: firmware version: B 4.0.2
[220843.023511] si2157 9-0060: Silicon Labs Si2147/2148/2157/2158 successfully attached
[220843.030075] sp2 8-0040: CIMaX SP2 successfully attached
[220843.030085] usb 1-2: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (Silicon Labs Si2168)...
[220843.058431] Registered IR keymap rc-tt-1500
[220843.058529] input: TechnoTrend TT-connect CT2-4650 CI v1.1 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/rc/rc0/input25
[220843.058616] rc rc0: TechnoTrend TT-connect CT2-4650 CI v1.1 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/rc/rc0
[220843.058619] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: schedule remote query interval to 300 msecs
[220843.058621] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: 'TechnoTrend TT-connect CT2-4650 CI v1.1' successfully initialized and connected
[220843.058647] usbcore: registered new interface driver dvb_usb_dvbsky
[220849.365260] dvb_ca adapter 0: DVB CAM detected and initialised successfully
```

As far as I can remember, this is *more or less* what turned up on the previous Ubuntu install as well - I particularly remember seeing the initialization of the CAM...

I have tried insmodding the required modules manually, with no result.

This is what appears in dmesg when I plug the USB cable to the device, with relevant modules loaded:

```
[ 3285.678512] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 3285.776059] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0b48, idProduct=3015
[ 3285.776065] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3285.776070] usb 1-1.1: Product: TechnoTrend USB2.0
[ 3285.776073] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: CityCom GmbH
[ 3285.776076] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: 20151107
```

Compared to OpenSuSE (and previous Ubuntu install) it's not much.

Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: V1 should be supported since kernel 3.18; V1.1 (yours) may not: https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/TechnoTrend_TT-connect_CT2-4650_CI

Comment: Actually yes. Checked dvb-usb-ids.h, and it only lists 0x3012 for version 1.0.

So obviously it is in 4.9 kernel, but not 4.4. Interesting.

Comment: Perhaps the firmware can be easily download and installed if offered at Additional Drivers like what happens with many other tuner chipsets. If not you may try the suggestions in the link above.

Comment: Firmware is OK - I've grabbed that manually. Anyway, that'd show up as a missing firmware in dmesg.

Comment: After a upgrade to 4.8 kernel, everything is fine. Thanks for providing the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to 4.8 fixed things. Turned out that the 4.4.0 kernel is too old.